# Crystal Report formula issue :How to split multi line text value in to the array and how to fetch it by forloop in

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

I have one field in a dataset which has a multi-line textbox value. I want to split that record, store it into an array, and when I fetch the value from the array by a for-loop, I want to prepend a "*" to each line.  I have  written a formula for that but it's working only for 2 values. After that it's not working and I'm not able to get how to retrieve the value like this.

I want the result to be:

```
* 123
* 234
* 786
```

But I'm getting the result:

```
*123
234
786
```

my formula is

```
Local StringVar y;
Local StringVar x;
Local NumberVar i;

y := ""+ chrw(10);
x := y;

Stringvar Array strings := Split({Touche.Concerns}, "\r\n");
Stringvar Array numbers;


For i :=1 To Ubound(strings) Do
(
y := y + chrw(10)+ "$" + strings[i];
);
y;
```

Comment: Your formula is _basically_ correct in its logic, but the code itself is messy and has typos in it. Go back over it and clean it up and you might find it'll work for you. To get you started: What are you using the `x` and `numbers` variables for? Why are you initializing your output string `y` the way you are? Double check the characters you're concatenating to your output.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a long formula which breaks into arrays and manipulates each line, why not just replace the line breaks with a line break *and* the asterisk?

`"* " & replace(trim({Touche.Concerns}), "\r\n", "\r\n* ");`

The leading '*' is to place the char on the first line and the `trim` function is called to remove any trailing line breaks (so there won't be a line with just the asterisk).

As a side note, use `&` when concatenating strings and not the `+` char. Use the `+` can sometimes cause coercion to where numeric values would be added together. For example `"12" + "34"` would yield `46` instead of `1234`. The `&` char ensures string concatenation is used.